# Not able to click an svg path element using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am working on automating charts data and below is how the data is represented.

```
<g style="cursor:pointer;" clip-path="url(#highcharts-2)" transform="translate(62,10) scale(1 1)" class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0 highcharts-tracker">
<path d="M 811 367.23566666666665 L 816 372.23566666666665 811 377.23566666666665 806 372.23566666666665 Z" fill="#18abc9"></path>
<path d="M 731 400.91344444444445 L 736 405.91344444444445 731 410.91344444444445 726 405.91344444444445 Z" fill="#18abc9"></path>
<path d="M 651 386.432 L 656 391.432 651 396.432 646 391.432 Z" fill="#18abc9"></path>
<path d="M 570 390.61766666666665 L 575 395.61766666666665 570 400.61766666666665 565 395.61766666666665 Z" fill="#18abc9"></path>
<path d="M 490 381.09166666666664 L 495 386.09166666666664 490 391.09166666666664 485 386.09166666666664 Z" fill="#18abc9">
</path><path d="M 410 334.905 L 415 339.905 410 344.905 405 339.905 Z" fill="#18abc9"></path></g>
```

I have written the following Selenium code to click on the first path element.

```
List<WebElement> a = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='path' and contains(@fill, '#090')])[1]"));
Actions actionBuilder = new Actions(driver);
actionBuilder.click(a.get(0)).build().perform();
```

The list `a` has just one webelement received. The program throws error when trying to click.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point     (904, 556.86669921875). Other element would receive the click: `<path d="M 801 341.00352 L 806 346.00352 801 351.00352 796 346.00352 Z" fill="#090"></path>`

The path I provided in the error is not exactly the same as the DOM I provided.

Comment: Try using `JavascriptExecutor` then as `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()" ,a.get(0));` and let me know

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur It throws org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: arguments[0].click is not a function

Comment: It should be arguments[0].cli‌​ck(), you are missing `()`. Please correct it.

Comment: Sorry. Its just a log I provided. I have () in

Comment: ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();",a.get(0));

Comment: Now it's correct, are you still getting same exception??

Comment: Yes. I am getting the exception I provided,

Comment: Strange, code is absolutely correct! Try once typing same manually and execute instead of copy paste

Comment: Thanks. I tried entering that manually. There is some known issue with firefox about the error I provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123983/discussion-between-saurabh-gaur-and-chanchow).

Comment: Ok try once using  WebDriverWait to wait until element getting visible and clickable before click as `new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(a.get(0))).click()` and let me know

Comment: Same error. other element receiving the click.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that another path element is overlapping the path you want to click. I'm guessing that the path is oddly shaped and Selenium is trying to click the middle of it and ends up clicking the other path. You can try [`moveToElement()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveToElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-int-int-) in `Actions` and play with the offsets until you get it right.